# returning an ObjectQuery<T> from the objectQuery using reflection

Tags: entity-framework

I have one method which is returning the object of ObjectQuery in this ObjectQuery object the type of object is ObjectQuery, now i want to include table in this object 
using reflection, i called the method Include using reflection for this but i m getting the error can someone please tell me the error. here is the sample code.

```
ObjectQuery objTest = LoadEntitiy(entites,entityClassType);


public ObjectQuery LoadEntitiy(ClientEntities entities, Type entityClasstype)
        {
            PropertyInfo pi = entities.GetType().GetProperties().First(item => item.Name == entityClasstype.Name.ToString());
            Object obj = pi.GetValue(entities, null);
            Type objContext = obj.GetType();
            return (ObjectQuery)obj;
        }
```

now i m calling the method for including it using the reflection that is here

```
Type lstType = typeof(ObjectQuery<>); 
Type constructedType = lstType.MakeGenericType(typeof(ObjectQuery<>)); 
MethodInfo addListItemMethod = constructedType.GetMethod("Include"); 
addListItemMethod.Invoke(objTest, new object[] {"tablename" });
```

Comment: that is the most ridiculous first sentence i've ever seen.  try replacing 'object' with 'instance', and i think the question will make more sense. also, what are the error details?  regardless, i don't really understand the question.

Comment: i have one object of Type objectQuery and i want to include one table in the particular object but its not getting loaded in the object

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to define a convention to always "Include" a certain set of data.

This convention is normally known as eager loading and there are alternatives like lazy loading.

EF 4.1 or greater already includes functionality to do this for you, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg715120(v=vs.103).aspx

Comment: i got the answer for the question, include method has return type and to load the tables we need to get the result in some object unless its not going to load your tables in the tables.

Answer (score 0):

```
Type lstType = typeof(ObjectQuery<>); 
Type constructedType = lstType.MakeGenericType(typeof(T(which u want to send as parameter))); 
MethodInfo addListItemMethod = constructedType.GetMethod("Include"); 
object objtest = addListItemMethod.Invoke(objTest, new object[] {"tblname" });
```

Now the objtest contains the all the table names which you want to include.